# How to createTempFile inside clojail?

Tags: security, clojure, permissions, sandbox, java-security

I am using [Clojail](https://github.com/Raynes/clojail) to sandbox my application.
I want to process an Excel(xlsx) file inside my application.
The code involves using `clojure.excel` which eventually tries to use Java's `createTempFile` API.
Because of Security issues i am getting following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to create temporary file
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2018)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2070)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.common.XBeanDebug.log(XBeanDebug.java:97)
```

This is how i currently create my sandbox.

```
    (:require  [clojail.jvm :refer [permissions domain context]]
               [clojail.core :refer [sandbox eagerly-consume]])

(let [context (-> (permissions (FilePermission. file-path "read"))
                    domain
                    context)
        namespace-form (namespace-declaration)
        sb (sandbox modified-secure-tester-without-def
                    :init namespace-form
                    :namespace (namespace-symbol namespace-form)
                    :context context
                    :transform eagerly-consume
                    :timeout (* 5 60 1000) ;; 5 minute timeout
                    :max-defs 500)]
    (log/log-env :info "build-sandbox")
    sb)
```

How can i modify my permissions and context to allow createTempFile to execute?

Can anyone please help me with some suggestions or similar solutions?

Comment: Not a solution, but I've used `docjure` before to process excel files and it was quite easy if I remember. https://github.com/mjul/docjure

Comment: @Josh Thanks,I will have a look. But did you use it inside a sandbox?

Comment: i didn't use it in a sandbox